# Type-Casting a request parameter in JSP

Tags: jsp, exception, numbers, format

I am trying to type-cast the request parameter "gross" and it is throwing an Number Format Exception.

Below is my JSP:

```
  <%
    if (request != null) `enter code here`
             {
    String gross = request.getParameter("gross");   //GROSS PARAM
    int grossSal = Integer.parseInt(gross);          //Type-Casting
    double netSal = 0;
%>

<jsp:useBean id="emp" class="com.source.EmpPOJO" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="id" />
<jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="name" />
<jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="desg" />
<jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="gross" value='<%=grossSal%>' />


<%
    netSal = emp.calculateNet();
    }
%>
```

Comment: You should not use `Scriplets` in your JSP page. Use JSTL tags. And it will do automatic Type Coercion for you.

Answer (score 1):

change your code as i have updated below:

```
<%
if (request != null) `enter code here`
         {
String gross = request.getParameter("gross");   //GROSS PARAM
if(gross!=null)
{
    int grossSal = Integer.parseInt(gross);          //Type-Casting
}
double netSal = 0;
%>
```

I have added `if(gross!=null)`, because your scriplet also runs when your form loads,and that time if it does not get the value which is needed it will give exception.